# Reusing the same screens in multiple React Navigation navigators without copy-pasting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I currently have a BottomTabNavigator with Five Stack Navigators within. Some screens should be reachable from every Tab, so I have essentially 'copy-pasted' them into every navigator. It works fine, but I'd like to avoid copy-pasting code. I'd want them specified in one file and then just 'imported' into every navigator.

To illustrate, the structure is:

```
// Tab 1
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="A" component={XXX} />
  <Stack.Screen name="B" component={XXX} />
  <Stack.Screen name="C" component={XXX} />
</Stack.Navigator>

// Tab 2
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="D" component={XXX} />
  <Stack.Screen name="B" component={XXX} />
  <Stack.Screen name="C" component={XXX} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

and my first approach was:

```
// common-screens.tsx

export const CommonScreens = ({Stack}) => (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="B" component={XXX} />
    <Stack.Screen name="C" component={XXX} />
  </>
)

// navigators.tsx

// Tab 1
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="A" component={XXX} />
  <CommonScreens Stack={Stack} />
</Stack.Navigator>

// Tab 2
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="D" component={XXX} />
  <CommonScreens Stack={Stack} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

However, this causes the error `A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'CommonScreens')`

How would you suggest implementing this?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you make a function to generate a list of `<Stack.Screen/>`.

```
const getScreens = (screenArray) => {
  return screenArray.map((props) => {
    return <Stack.Screen {...props} />
  })
}
```

Then use the function like shown below

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {getScreens([
    { name: 'A', component: 'X' },
    { name: 'B', component: 'XX' },
    { name: 'C', component: 'XXX' },
  ])}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

To further make it easier, you can have a mapping of all names and components.
Just pass the name in an array and map components based on it.

Example:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  {getScreens(['A', 'B', 'C'])}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Note that this code is just to give you an idea.
I have not tested this code.

Comment: Thanks Raj! Was looking for something more concise but it looks like it might not be possible, so I'll go with something along the lines of what you suggested

Comment: You can make CommonScreens as a function and rather than calling it as a component, call it as a function then you will achieve your desired result.

Comment: Also, make sure to remove <>...</> in CommonScreens function. You don't need to wrap it in Fragment

Comment: Will this affect performance?

Comment: I've seen this approach but honestly I don't love it. The purpose of the reusability, in my opinion, largely for clarity rather than to simplify a complex process. You introduce a new "style" here which ... idk ... it's fine but at this point I'd rather just maintain style consistency and write a tiny bit more code than do this. imo react navigation should have a standard way of grouping reusable screens to deal with this issue...

Comment: @pfcodes I don't think this will cause any performance issues, but I have not compared performance to back my opinion.

Comment: @AlecMather I understand you, brother, as I know there is no ideal solution for the problem shared, I provided this solution as we can move the stack code to a JSON file and handle everything there which makes it a little easier to manage on a large project.